# How to calculate javascript and jquery speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

In my Application, many places i used **javascript and jquery** functions.
Some times javascript progress making **too slow to perform actions**.

I able to see the speed after progress is complete via firefox tool.

Is there any way to calculate javascript working speed while script is on progress.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use many tools, [**jspref**](http://jsperf.com/) website will allow you to even compare performance with different codes.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebInspector's or [IE F12 Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbowen/archive/2011/06/27/internet-explorer-9-developer-tools-deep-dive-part-4-profiling-javascript.aspx).